# nsis : how to protect files extraction from 7zip file manager

Tags: nsis, 7zip, copy-protection

i would be glad to know if it is possible to protect the setup file from 7zip ? when you make "open with 7z" you can extract any files from your setup , there is a way to protect them ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NSIS is open-source and will therefore always be susceptible to decompilation.

The best option is to re-compile NSIS yourself (admittedly this is a bit hard to do). After downloading the source you would have to reorder a couple of the EW_ entries in \Source\exehead\fileform.h. For example, move `EW_CALL` down to after `EW_LOCKWINDOW` and the build NSIS (you must build makensis and the stubs as a minimum). 7-zip will not be able to decompile your installers made with this custom NSIS.

The other option is to [encrypt your files](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/DcryptDll_:_Adding_Encryption_to_NSIS). Anyone with access to a debugger will be able to find your encryption password though.

If you are doing this to prevent piracy; it is much better to put the protection in the installed application, not the installer...

Comment: for the moment the solution that i found that is "NSISBI". as the dev, can you add checkbox somewhere to encrypt the files ? or it must be recompiled each time  and it is not possible ?

Comment: 7-zip will get NSISBI support I think. I don't understand the encryption question, you have to encrypt each time your applications changes.

Comment: no ; NSISBI  can't  open the setup. ( so it's protected ) , my question is - how to block 7zip support for setup.exe

Comment: i have checked DcryptDll , but the example is very complicated , and it can not be build.  NGenKeys , is already copied to sys32 and accesible by cmd.exe so it shoud work